# Singular points of $ \sin ( \frac{1}{\cos\frac{1}{z}})$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, singularity

Specifically, $\displaystyle f(z) = \sin \left( \frac{1}{\displaystyle \cos \frac{1}{z}} \right)$ has singular points at $z = \displaystyle \frac{2}{\pi + 2\pi k}$, among others.

Now, I am trying to show that these are, in fact, essential singular points, but I am finding the process of doing so extremely difficult.

Writing out a Laurent Series would no doubt be extremely difficult, and so I was thinking about showing that the limit as $z \to \displaystyle \frac{2}{\pi + 2\pi k}$ does not exist, but that is also extremely hard.

Could somebody please help me get this problem done?

Thank you.

Comment: These are not essential singularities, they are simple poles. There is one essential singularity (and only one), at $z=0$ - because all these poles form a sequence that converges to 0.

Comment: @mathguy, I think we're using different terminologies, because I was taught that the limit of simple poles is not an isolated singularity, even an essential one.

Comment: @mathguy : no, $\cos(1/z)$ has simple zeros at $a_n = \pi/2 + k \pi$, hence  $\frac{1}{\cos(1/z)}$ has simple poles at $a_n$, and $\sin(C/z)$ has an essential singularity at $0$, hence $\sin(\frac{1}{\cos(1/z)})$ has  essential singularities at $a_n$

Comment: Err - you are both right (Jessy and user1952) - not paying attention.

Comment: @ Jessy : what is unclear in what I wrote, and why isn't it enough for you to prove that $f(z)$ has essential singularities at $a_n$ ? you know that if $g(z)$ is holomorphic on $z \in U$ (with $U$ an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$) and $h(z)$ holomorphic on $V$ some open subset containing $g(U)$, then $h(g(z))$ is holomorphic on $U$ ?

Comment: what result ???

Comment: @user1952009, okay, yes I know that, but that doesn't tell me specifically which kind of singularities I must have there.

Comment: @user1952009, it would help if you had a sequence I could exhibit (see RoberIsrael's answer below).

Comment: think deep to what I wrote : if $\frac{1}{\cos(1/z)}$ has a pole at $a_n$ then it is holomorphic on $0 < |z-a_n|  < \epsilon$, yes ? and $\sin(z)$ is holomorphic everywhere hence $\sin(\frac{1}{\cos(1/z)})$ is holomorphic on $0 < |z-a_n|  < \epsilon$, hence $a_n$ is an isolated singularity of $\sin(\frac{1}{\cos(1/z)})$

Comment: @user1952009, I'm not asking about a generic isolated singularity, I'm asking specifically about an **essential** singularity.

Comment: once you proved that it is an isolated singularity, all you have to do is proving that it is not a pole, which is obvious since around $a_n$, $\sin(\frac{1}{\cos(1/z)})$ is very close to $\sin(\frac{C}{z-a_n})$ (3rd time I write this)

Comment: @user1952009, what about showing it is not a removable singularity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's an isolated singularity, and neither a removable singularity nor a pole, then it must be an essential singularity.  To show this it suffices to find a sequence $z_n$ approaching the singularity such that $f(z_n)$ does not have a finite limit and does not go to complex $\infty$.  For example, 
$f(z_n)$ might alternate $\pm 1$.

Comment: okay...but what kind of sequence? Like $z_{n} = 1/z$? But that's not approaching the singularities $z = \frac{2}{\pi + 2\pi k}$, does it? My prof said something like "You can think of those points as where  $\cos $ has a simple zero, so the whole function is basically $\sin(1/z)$." But I don't understand what he meant.

Comment: $\sin(t) = \pm 1$ if $t$ is an odd multiple of $\pi/2$, say $(n+1/2) \pi$.  Then you want $t = 1/\cos(1/z_n)$, with $1/z_n$ near $\pi/2 + k \pi$...

Comment: or $z_{n}$ near $\frac{2}{\pi+2\pi k}$? I still don't know what sequence does that, though?

Comment: can you please elaborate. I can't figure out the sequence.

Comment: @JessyCat : it seems obvious that you never proved why $\sin(1/z)$ has an essential singularity at $z=0$

Comment: @user1952009, don't be snarky.

Comment: @JessyCat : ??? I am 99.9% sure that this is the point you didn't investigate, and there are different ways to prove it, the most obvious being that for $x$ real, $2\sin(1/(ix)) \sim e^{1/x}$  when $x \to 0$, it grows way too fast to be a pole.

Comment: If you write $1/z_n = \pi/2 + k \pi + s$, $\cos(1/z_n) = (-1)^{k+1} \sin(s)$, and this will be $1/t$ if $s = (-1)^{k+1} \arcsin(1/t)$.  As $n \to \infty$ you have $t = (n+1/2) \pi \to \infty$ so $1/t \to 0$ and $s \to 0$, i.e. $1/z_n \to \pi/2 + k \pi$ and $z_n \to 1/(\pi/2 + k\pi)$.